# c# windows can't close the app in the shutdown

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, system-shutdown

I have this problem: 
I built an application in c# .net 2.0 that is on the tray bar and everything works fine: if I click the close menu (that i've added) I call Close(); of the main form and everything is ok.
my problem is: if a person shutdown the pc without closing my application, windows seems to be not able to close this program and the shutdown routine is breaked.

a note: in my app I use a BackgroundWorker.

thanks in advance

Comment: Post the code where you are stopping the closing from happening normally

Comment: Without seeing the code my guess is that your application isn't properly handling the shutdown event. Do you handle the [Exit event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.exit.aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your application is doing something that is stopping windows from shutting down properly, you should handle the [`SystemEvents.SessionEnding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending.aspx) event in your application. This event is fired when the system is shutting down or the user is logging off.

In your event handler, do whatever is necessary to allow your application to be terminated gracefully, such as stopping all background workers / threads - etc.